# Moving an item in a list item only by one space based on user input

Tags: python

the code below was an implementation of a game between letter 'a' can only move to the right and letter b 'b' can move to the left

```
list1=[‘a’,’a’,’a’, ‘ ‘,’b’,’b’,’b’]

fr=int(input("Start Position"))
to=int(input("End Position"))

if list1[fr-1]=='a' and list1[to-1]==' ':
if list1[fr-1]=='b'and list[to-1]==' '

#swap code
list1[fr-1],list1[to-1]=list1[to-1],list1[fr-1]
```

Rules of the game

- cannot be swapped more than once space

by one space this is what I mean :
original list: `list1=[‘a’,’a’,’a’, ‘ ‘,’b’,’b’,’b’]`

if the user enter `from:1`
`to:4`
the transformation will look like this however this should not be executed and an error message should appear

`[‘ ‘,’a’,’a’,’a’,’b’,’b’,’b’]` -> # this code should not happen as It is not once space

this is what can happen

So it can either in this format :

`[‘a’,’a’,’a’, ‘ ‘,’b’,’b’,’b’]`# original list

user enters

`from:3`

`to:4`

To this

`[‘a’,’a’,’ ‘,‘a’,’b’,’b’,’b’]`

the same rule applies for frog 'b'

another scenario that can happen is
`[‘a’,’a’,’a’, ‘ ‘,’b’,’b’,’b’]`# original list

user enters
`from:6`
`to:4`

`[‘a’,’a’,’a’, ‘b‘,’b’,’ ’,’b’]`

So could anyone please help on how  to do code it

Comment: what do you mean by "restricting the movement of the places which cannot be more than one" ?
also your second example is not clear, please elaborate

Comment: I have update  my reasoning hope you understand it better

Comment: Your problem isn't clear (to me at least). if you have a link of your problem it would be better to give that instead of this description.

Comment: @Maaddy I have updated as much detail as I can hopefully you understand it better now

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

I gave the answer to this in the previous question you asked.You do not make any effort and do not follow the answers to the questions you ask.This is probably your homework or part of homework and you just wait for a solution.I hope you will share your works and then ask questions, this can be better for your improvement.

I am sharing my answer again because maybe it can help others and the previous question was deleted.I hope this answer works.

Please share your work before asking questions next time and follow your question and their answers otherwise you may not be able to solve your problem.

```
  puzzle =["a","a","a"," ","b","b","b"]
## dont forget your input will start 0
## because you will pick an index

def move(puzzle):
    move_index = int(input("enter an index for move right"))
    for i in puzzle:
      if move_index < len(puzzle):
        if puzzle[move_index + 1] == " " and puzzle[move_index] == "a":
            puzzle[move_index],puzzle[move_index+1] = puzzle[move_index +1 ],puzzle[move_index] ## if right index is free,move
            return puzzle
        if puzzle[move_index - 1] == " " and puzzle[move_index] == "b" :
            puzzle[move_index], puzzle[move_index - 1] = puzzle[move_index - 1], puzzle[move_index]
            return puzzle
        if puzzle[move_index - 2] == " " and puzzle[move_index-1] == "a" and puzzle[move_index] == "b":
            puzzle[move_index], puzzle[move_index - 2] = puzzle[move_index - 2], puzzle[move_index]
            return puzzle
        if puzzle[move_index + 2] == " " and puzzle[move_index + 1 ] == "b" and puzzle[move_index] == "a" :
            puzzle[move_index], puzzle[move_index + 2] = puzzle[move_index + 2], puzzle[move_index]
            return puzzle

      if move_index == len(puzzle): ## you can move last element only for your conditons
          puzzle.append(puzzle.pop(move_index-1)) ## switch for last and first
          puzzle.insert(0, puzzle.pop())
          return puzzle ## updated puzzle
      else:
        return puzzle

def game():
    is_game_continue = int(input("Do you want continue ? (1) Yes (2) No")) ## for enter new moves
    return is_game_continue

while game() == 1: ##  if user want continue
    ## you can add other options like return value != 1
    current_puzzle = move(puzzle)
    print(current_puzzle)
```

Comment: the solution you provided only targeted letters moving to the right and not left

Comment: You can move left just with "B".If conditions are OK.

Answer (score 0):

You have all the ideas about the rules so I think you can finish the game by yourself. This answer may serve as a reference for you to put ideas together.

```
start_puzzle = ['a', 'a', 'a', ' ', 'b', 'b', 'b']
end_puzzle = ['b', 'b', 'b', ' ', 'a', 'a', 'a']

print(start_puzzle)
while start_puzzle != end_puzzle:
    # -1 to get index
    from_idx = int(input("Move from position: ")) - 1
    to_idx = int(input("Move to position: ")) - 1
    # positive step from left to right and negative step from right to left
    step = to_idx - from_idx

    if 0 <= from_idx < len(start_puzzle) and 0 <= to_idx < len(start_puzzle):
        if start_puzzle[from_idx] == "a" and step < 0 or start_puzzle[from_idx] == "b" and step > 0:
            print(f"'{start_puzzle[from_idx]}' cannot move backwards.")
        elif start_puzzle[to_idx] != ' ':
            print("Can only move to empty space.")
        elif step > 2 or step < -2:
            print("Cannot swap more than one space.")
        else:
            start_puzzle[from_idx], start_puzzle[to_idx] = start_puzzle[to_idx], start_puzzle[from_idx]
    else:
        print("Position out of range.")
    print(start_puzzle)

if start_puzzle == end_puzzle:
    print("You Won!!")
```

Test result:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', ' ', 'b', 'b', 'b']
Move from position: 1
Move to position: 8
Position out of range.

['a', 'a', 'a', ' ', 'b', 'b', 'b']
Move from position: 1
Move to position: 4
Cannot swap more than one space.

['a', 'a', 'a', ' ', 'b', 'b', 'b']
Move from position: 3
Move to position: 5
Can only move to empty space.

['a', 'a', 'a', ' ', 'b', 'b', 'b']
Move from position: 3
Move to position: 4
['a', 'a', ' ', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
Move from position: 4
Move to position: 3
'a' cannot move backwards.
['a', 'a', ' ', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
Move from position: 5
Move to position: 3
['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', ' ', 'b', 'b']
Move from position: 3
Move to position: 5
'b' cannot move backwards.
.
.
.
['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', ' ', 'a', 'a']
Move from position: 4
Move to position: 5
['b', 'b', 'b', ' ', 'a', 'a', 'a']
You Won!!
```

Answer (score -2):

You should not use `from` as a variable since it's a reserved keyword in python.

Maybe that's what causing your problem.

Comment: but okay lets say i change it to `fr` that still doesn't meet the once space condition